# Multiprocessing for calculating eigen value

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm generating 100 random int matrices of size `1000x1000`. I'm using the multiprocessing module to calculate the eigen values of the 100 matrices.

The code is given below:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def calEigen():

 S, U = np.linalg.eigh(a)

def multiprocess(processes):
 pool = mp.Pool(processes=processes)
 #Start timing here as I don't want to include time taken to initialize the processes
 start = timeit.default_timer()
 results = [pool.apply_async(calEigen, args=())]
 stop = timeit.default_timer()
 print (processes":", stop - start) 

 results = [p.get() for p in results]
 results.sort() # to sort the results 


if __name__ == "__main__":

 global a
 a=[]

 for i in range(0,100):
  a.append(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(1000,1000)))

 #Print execution time without multiprocessing
 start = timeit.default_timer()
 calEigen()
 stop = timeit.default_timer()
 print stop - start 

 #With 1 process
 multiprocess(1)

 #With 2 processes
 multiprocess(2)

 #With 3 processes
 multiprocess(3)

 #With 4 processes
 multiprocess(4)
```

The output is

```
0.510247945786
('Process:', 1, 5.1021575927734375e-05)
('Process:', 2, 5.698204040527344e-05)
('Process:', 3, 8.320808410644531e-05)
('Process:', 4, 7.200241088867188e-05)
```

Another iteration showed this output:

```
 69.7296020985
 ('Process:', 1, 0.0009050369262695312)
 ('Process:', 2, 0.023727893829345703)
 ('Process:', 3, 0.0003509521484375)
 ('Process:', 4, 0.057518959045410156)
```

My questions are these:

1. Why doesn't the time execution time reduce as the number of
   processes increase? Am I using the multiprocessing module correctly?
2. Am I calculating the execution time correctly?

I have edited the code given in the comments below. I want the serial and multiprocessing functions to find the eigen values for the same list of 100 matrices. The edited code is-

```
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

a=[]

for i in range(0,100):
 a.append(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(1000,1000)))

def serial(z):
 result = []
 start_time = time.time()
 for i in range(0,100):    
  result.append(np.linalg.eigh(z[i])) #calculate eigen values and append to result list
 end_time = time.time()
 print("Single process took :", end_time - start_time, "seconds")


def caleigen(c):  
 result = []        
 result.append(np.linalg.eigh(c)) #calculate eigenvalues and append to result list
 return result

def mp(x):
 start_time = time.time()
 with Pool(processes=x) as pool:  # start a pool of 4 workers
  result = pool.map_async(caleigen,a)   # distribute work to workers
  result = result.get() # collect result from MapResult object
 end_time = time.time()
 print("Mutltiprocessing took:", end_time - start_time, "seconds" )

if __name__ == "__main__":

 serial(a)
 mp(1,a)
 mp(2,a)
 mp(3,a)
 mp(4,a)
```

There is no reduction in the time as the number of processes increases. Where am I going wrong? Does multiprocessing divide the list into chunks for the processes or do I have to do the division?

Comment: You are not dividing the work and distribute it to your processes. So the is no collaboration. Its more like each process is doing the full computation on its own and its slower when you have more processes doing the same thing simultaneously due to more CPU load than when one process is doing it. If you divide your work and distribute it to your workers, it should be faster.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the multiprocessing module correctly. As @dopstar pointed out, you're not dividing your task. There is only one task for the process pool, so not matter how many workers you assigned, only one will get the job. As for your second question, I didn't use `timeit` to measure process time precisely. I just use `time` module to get a crude sense of how fast things are. It serves the purpose most of the time, though. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this should be the single process version of your code

```
import numpy as np
import time

result = []
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    a = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(1000,1000))  #generate random matrix
    result.append(np.linalg.eigh(a))                 #calculate eigen values and append to result list
end_time = time.time()
print("Single process took :", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

The single process version took 15.27 seconds on my computer. Below is the multiprocess version, which took only 0.46 seconds on my computer. I also included the single process version for comparison. (The single process version has to be enclosed in the `if` block as well and placed after the multiprocess version.) Because you would like to repeat your calculation for 100 times, it'd be a lot easier to create a pool of workers and let them take on unfinished task automatically than to manually start each process and specify what each process should do. Here in my codes, the argument for the `caleigen` call is merely to keep track of how many times the task has been executed. Finally, `map_async` is generally faster than `apply_async`, with its downside being consuming slightly more memory and taking only one argument for function call. The reason for using `map_async` but not `map` is that in this case, the order in which result is returned does not matter and `map_async` is much faster than `map`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import time

def caleigen(x):     # define work for each worker
    a = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(1000,1000))   
    S, U = np.linalg.eigh(a)                        
    return S, U


if __name__ == "main":
    start_time = time.time()
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:      # start a pool of 4 workers
        result = pool.map_async(caleigen, range(100))   # distribute work to workers
        result = result.get()        # collect result from MapResult object
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Mutltiprocessing took:", end_time - start_time, "seconds" )

    # Run the single process version for comparison. This has to be within the if block as well. 
    result = []
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        a = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(1000,1000))  #generate random matrix
        result.append(np.linalg.eigh(a))                 #calculate eigen values and append to result list
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Single process took :", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: Great answer; however, the multiprocessing is not working with my multiprocessing machine. it takes 0.s:) Is the code working at your computer?

Comment: Yes, it is working on my computer. That's how I got those time measurement ;)  It seems that the `if __name__ == "main":` block is not running on you machine. This is most likely because you're not running it as the main process. ( Which is exactly the condition this line is testing). How did you test the code? You should save the above text in a .py file, run the file.

Comment: @user3667217 I edited your code as I want both serial and multiprocessing to find the eigen values for the same 100 matrices.

Comment: If you want to do both, do the `multiprocessing` one first and you have to put the single process version in the `if` block as well. See my updated answer.  You can try not doing so and see what happens.

Comment: @user3667217 I edited the code to perform multiprocessing before single process. The time doesn't reduce. Why does multiprocessing have to be performed before single process? Also, do I have to divide the list of 100 matrices into chunks for each process in multiprocessing?

Comment: @Misha, two things to clarify : 1) Did you try my code without any editing and see if works?  2) How many cores do you have in your cpu? You can use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` to see how many cores you have. If you have only one core, then it's apparent why you won't get any improvement in timing. If my code above works and your edited version doesn't, please post your edited version so I can see what may go wrong.

Comment: @Misha, the `with` block for the multiprocess pool blocks the main program from progressing until it finishes. There is no such mechanism in the single process version of the code provided above so it enters the pool and spawn other processes before it finished the task. That's why you'll see the single process output multiple times.

Comment: @Misha  You need to divide the task because `mutliprocessing` does not do it for you. If you don't divide it, you'll just let one process handle all the computation and there will be no speed up at all. In your code, you actually let multiple workers do exactly the same thing. That's duplicate effort.